# why my spring boot project trying to connect at may postgresql database with my windows user and not my superuser?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, spring-data-jpa, connection, superuser

Good evening,
I have created a project with spring and i'm trying to do connection with my postgresql database with this configuration
[image]

But when i execute my program , i have this issue:
[image]

fabie is my windows user and not my superuser.
why my application trying to connect with my windows user instead of my superuser.

My file pg_hba.conf
[image]

My file postgresql.conf
[image]

Please help me to understand and to resolve my issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the property `spring.datasource.username` set? In the `application.properties` file or somewhere else? What [relative] location is that file at?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i had spring.datasource.user instead of spring.datasource.username in my application.properties. Now it works.